# Python - Insert a dictionary as value into a new dictionary with same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My function give me a dictionary in following format-

```
{
  "key1": {
    "deleted": [],
    "inserted": []
  },
  "key2": {
    "deleted": [
      {
        "end": 5,
        "line": "",
        "start": 5
      }
```

However, I want to have this output as below -

```
 {  "section1":
                    {
                        "name":"key1",
                        "deleted":[],
                        "inserted":[],
                    }
          },
    {  "section2":
                    {
                        "name":"key2",
                        "deleted":[],
                        "inserted":[],
                    }
          },

{  "section3":
                    {
                        "name":"key3",
                        "deleted":[],
                        "inserted":[],
                    }
          },
```

The function I have written is -

```
diff_data = {}

    with open('2018temp.json', 'w') as f1t, open('2019temp.json', 'w') as f2t:
        json.dump(f1_dict, f1t)
        json.dump(f2_dict, f2t)

    for section in settings['includes']:
        f1_text = f1_dict.get(section, [])
        f2_text = f2_dict.get(section, [])
        diffile = []
        diff = difflib.Differ()
        with open('diffile.txt', 'a') as f:
            for line in diff.compare(f1_text, f2_text):
                f.write(line + ('\n' if not line.endswith('\n') else ''))
                if line.startswith(("-", "+", "?")):
                    diffile.append(line)

        data = {'deleted': [], 'inserted': []}

        for i, line in enumerate(diffile[:-1]):
            if line.startswith('-'):
                if diffile[i+1].startswith('?'): # Deletion and modification
                    updated_line = diffile[i+2]
                    update_start = re.search('[-+^]', diffile[i+1]).start()
                    update_end = re.search('[-+^][^-+^]*$', diffile[i+1]).start()
                    data['deleted'].append({'line': diffile[i+2][2:], 'start': update_start, 'end': update_end})
                elif diffile[i+1].startswith('+') and i+2 < len(diffile) and diffile[i+2].startswith('?'):
                    pass # Addition and modification, do nothing
                else:
                    data['deleted'].append(line[2:]) # Pure deletion
            elif line.startswith('+'):
                if diffile[i+1].startswith('?'): # Addition and modification
                    update_start = re.search('[-+^]', diffile[i+1]).start()
                    update_end = re.search('[-+^][^-+^]*$', diffile[i+1]).start()
                    data['inserted'].append({'line': line[2:], 'start': update_start, 'end': update_end})
                else:
                    data['inserted'].append(line[2:]) # Pure addition

        diff_data[section] = data
```

I tried to change *diff_data[section] = data* to -

```
diff_data.setdefault('section',[]).append(data)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

    diff_data['section'].append(data)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
diff_data.append({'section': [data]})
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Any clue, how should I approach this. It seems to be a simple problem, but I am not able to get the formatting correctly as the required output. The key for all the values in output needs to be *"section"*, which is adding complexity to get the correct output.

Comment: At first glance, did you mean to use "section" twice as a key (which is by design impossible)? If so then you may want just a list of objects, which is a pretty easy change. Or was that supposed to be like "section1", "section2"? You put a good bit of effort into the example, so you might as well finish the job so I can actually run it to recreate your issue.

Comment: You can't have same keys in one dictionary, this is not what dictionary is. Have look at [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) again.

Comment: As @EkremDİNÇEL mentioned, having the same key is going to cause collisions, meaning the latest "section" will always end up overwriting the previous one in your dictionary. You'll have to follow the JSON convention (a list of "section objects") if you want to store multiple "sections", i.e.: `{ "sections": [ {"name": "key1", "deleted": [], ... }, ... ] }`

Comment: @KennyOstrom: I did mean using the "section" twice, however, I think based on the explanations in the comment, I will have to use- 'section1, section2. I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: You should use the "key1" and "key2" that you already have, or convert it to an array. However, you can add "name" even though it is redundant (I wouldn't). The real question is WHY do you want the wrong output? We might be able to help there.